# FogBugz SVN integration like Trac does?

Tags: svn, trac, fogbugz

Does FogBugz integrate with SVN like Trac does?

Comment: You might want to add "(SVN integration)" to the question title.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes!

[FogBugz 6 Source Control Integration](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/docs/60/topics/advanced/Sourcecontrolintegration.html)

Basically, you set up an svn post-commit hook script that checks for the presence of a FogBugz Case # in the commit message.  I usually set up my hook script to look for the string "BUGZID:  NNN".

If you use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/), you can even configure it so that there's a box for entering the case # right on the Commit dialog.

If it finds a valid case #, it adds a bunch of information about the commit to the FogBugz case.

[image]